# OpenCart 2.2 error undefined when viewing order info

Tags: opencart

When I click the view button next to an order (whether from the dashboard or orders page) I get an "error undefined" alert as the page is loading.

I also get the same error when I try and change the order status from the same page and it yields no results.

It also produces no errors in the error log.

I can however change the order status from the edit order page but this is very inconvenient.

If anyone knows a common solution or maybe pointers as to how to start diagnosing the issue please post them here. I've been hunting for answers most of the day and have had no luck with any solutions.

ty in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SSL Tyr this at upload/admin/controller/sale/order.php

After

```
 $data['store_name'] = $order_info['store_name'];
```

Remove

```
$data['store_url'] = $this->request->server['HTTPS'] ? preg_replace("/^http:\/\//", "https://", $order_info['store_url']) : $order_info['store_url'];
```

Add

```
$data['store_url'] = $this->request->server['HTTPS'] ? HTTPS_CATALOG : HTTP_CATALOG;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately OpenCart 2.2.0.0 is known to be a bit buggy.

Best thing would be to start using 2.3.0.2 (avoid 2.3.0.0 and 2.3.0.1) if possible.